# What does having a humanity rating of 6 mean for a 380 year old Toreador Vampire? What about a Humanity of 7 for a 150 year old Toreador Vampire?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade

I'm thinking of playing a Vampire of the Masquerade game and I'm very much thinking of having the two main NPCs that the players interact with be of the Toreador Clan.

In this case the first one is a 380 year old Vampire with a humanity rating of 6. The second one is a 150 year old Vampire with a humanity of 7.

So pretty high humanity for their ages. I haven't written any more more about them yet but I would appreciate everyone pointing me in the right direction for this.

For such two vampires, what are some things to keep in mind when interacting with other vampires, within their clans and outside it, and mortals?

Comment: Why are you asking essentially [the same question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/202911/28941), *again*? You've already been told what humanity 7 means, and humanity 6 is only a little less human.

Comment: No. My question is a bit different from my previous one

Comment: @ColonizeroftheSun I fail to see what this question will get you that the other does not already. Perhaps you could clarify how you feel they are different? It seems we don't understand what sort of info or clarification you're looking for.

Comment: Well I'm asking for a specific Clan here. And to build to npcs. So I'm more specific. And it's different.

Comment: @Jason_c_o I see the differences, even though the title questions are similar at first glance. The other questions wants to know what the humanity system is about, the age and humanity in the title are just a random example. This question wants to know how two vampires of a specific age, humanity, and clan would behave as NPCs. The other question is looking for a rule explanation, this one is looking for an analysis of possible NPCs (though I'm not sure there is enough information given for a solid answer).

Answer (score 3):

### High humanity-rating older vampires

Although it's not explicitly enforced a general assumption is that as vampires age they will often lose Humanity, fall out of touch with human emotions, human perceptions, and the human race and become alien both as a natural consequence of society changing and their own inhuman nature and resulting psychological problems.

Ergo, if an older vampire has a high humanity rating, they have likely made an effort.  They keep up with the latest trends.  They have a psychologist.  They put time, money and effort into interacting with human society on a regular basis - they go to raves, they play chess with old men in the park, they watch and care about reality tv shows.  They might even work a job, go on dates, or collect action figures.

To portray a character like this, show this process in action.  Have the party meet them as they are on their treadmill with a PA handing them a smoothie bottle and time-checking them, or they ask the party to pick up some promotional object at a job fair and bring that back in addition to their other task(s).  Have them whip out pop culture references that are out of date, realize they are out of date, apologize, and drop instead something that only tweens use.  Show the effort the vampire is putting in to remain 'current'.

Likewise, show the effort the vampire is putting in to retain empathy.  Have them intentionally force themselves to do something less advantageous for them because it is 'right', or take a moment to intentionally feel the appropriate emotion.

Retaining humanity as a vampire is the process of practicing a quality which is no longer automatic, or rather, that is largely the best way to portray it.  There are other options or means by which a vampire could maintain humanity, but they are generally more complicated and harder to portray.  'Putting some effort in' is the easiest to show and also often the most entertaining for the players (your audience).

Comment: Thanks. So what would either of those two vampires look like or be like? Like how does humanity of 6 or 7 now look like here?