# What systems would need to be in place for a 610-year-old Toreador Vampire to maintain a humanity rating of 8 for so long?

Tags: world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-dark-ages, vampire-20th-anniversary

I'm trying to make a female vampire who's, 610 years old and Toreador have such a high humanity rating. I'm kind of not sure what are some recommendations onto how she has been able to maintain such a high rating or ranking for so long.

So I'm open to answers onto how.

Currently referencing *Vampire: The Masquerade 20th Anniversary Edition – The Dark Ages*.

Comment: @fectin: This is the third question the OP has asked that constitutes essentially the same question asked with slight variations (exact humanity rating and age of vampire are the only variables). It's all at largely opinion-based, and the answer is largely going to be up to the Storyteller; the OP can come up with reasons on their own. See [What does having a Humanity rating of 7 mean for a 150 Year old Vampire?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/202911/28941) and [What does having a humanity rating of 6 mean for a 380 year old Toreador Vampire?...](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/202916/28941).

Comment: @ShadowRanger Oh. Fair enough then.

Answer (score 4):

By never losing interest in nor connection with humanity. Instead of withdrawing into the world of vampires and eternal sleep, she has kept in touch with normal humans, through pain and loss, through birth and death.

Perhaps she has followed her mortal family as an eccentric aunt and/or patron, perhaps she has followed her aesthetic interests into the throngs of humans who produce the art.

She has never stopped loving, never let grief prevent her from finding new people to connect with, and she has treasured those people - perhaps even more now than she did as a mortal.

It is highly likely that events during her mortal life would have served a major role in shaping her outlook on life. With an age of 610 years, the standard start year of Dark Ages 20th, 1242, would have her birth year coincide with the passing of the Prophet, 632.

### Arabia

If she was born anywhere near Arabia, the ongoing Arab-Byzantine wars would have been something she was aware of, and perhaps experienced as something either positive or negative.

Perhaps her family lived in Ascalon, which fell when she was seven, and were forced to emigrate to Constantinopolis, where she learned to love living close to so many people, and so much art.

Perhaps her family were part of the invading Arab forces - an Arab father and, perhaps, a Roman mother. After a somewhat tumultuous first few years, her family may have settled as part of the new ruling elite of occupied territory, where she learned to appreciate different cultures and artistic expressions.

### China

During the early-mid 7th century, Christianity was establishing itself in China. In 638, the Emperor of the Tang issued an edict declaring all religions to be tolerated within his Empire. The same year, a Nestorian church was built in the Tang capital.

Perhaps the introduction of a new culture and new religion gave her a way of looking at life that she has kept with her ever since.

Perhaps she was a child of a Christan missionary, raised in two cultures from the very start.

### Francia

More than a hundred years before Charlemagne, the seeds of his Empire were growing in fertile soil. However, internecine strife was rife, and after Dagobert I's death in 639, a rebellion arose which caused the beginning of a period of troubles that lasted until Pepin II won Francia for what would become the Carolingian dynasty.

Perhaps she was born to a noble family forced to forsake their heritage, teaching her a deeper appreciation for family and relations over material possessions.